# File directory doesn't exist with context.getFilesDir()

Tags: java, android, file

As an Newbie in I/O, I've read and tried using the examples from  [this](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html#WriteInternalStorage)
and [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html). However, I'm just unable to create a simple directory in the internal storage. Must've been a typo somewhere.

For my app I've defined the FileProvider with the following file_paths.xml for storing app internal files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path name="ma_pics" path="pictures/" />
</paths>
```

A simple method below should provide a file that resides inside the "pictures" directory, but my problem is when I try to create the a directory, the directory simply doesn't exist. What am I doing wrong?

```
@Nonnull
public final File providePictureFile(@Nonnull String prefix, @Nonnull String suffix)
            throws IOException {
        File picturesDir = new File(mContext.getFilesDir(), "pictures");
        if(!picturesDir.exists()){
            // code forks here, dir doesn't exist, throws the following exception
            throw new IOException("Pictures dir doesn't exist");
        }
        return new File(picturesDir, prefix + suffix);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I try to create the a directory

You do not have any code that creates a directory. You are creating a `File` object, which does not automatically create something on the filesystem. Call `mkdirs()` on `picturesDir` to create that directory.

Comment: Thank you, that solves it. I got confused with creating dir vs opening a dir.